# Nos hace sentirnos o Nos hace sentir

Tags: pronombres

¿Qué forma es correcta? y ¿qué regla se aplica en estos casos?

> Nos hace sentirnos.

o

> Nos hace sentir.

---

> Me hace sentirme.

o

> Me hace sentir.

---

> Te hace sentirte.

o

> Te hace sentir.

Answer (score 10):

En el Manual de la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española, apartado 16.4.3a. Última frase.

> Se consideran también incorrectas las construcciones, propias de la lengua descuidada, en las que el mismo pronombre aparece a la vez como enclítico y como proclítico: *se debe respetarse cualquier opinión; *se lo tengo que decírselo

[fundeu.es](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/hiperbaton/)

Así, de las opciones que das a escoger, las correctas son:

> Nos hace sentir / Me hace sentir / Te hace sentir.

Si añades el mismo pronombre proclítico como enclítico, o viceversa, es redundante.

Para las reglas añado una parte del texto de la RAE acerca los [pronombres personales átonos](https://www.google.com/search?q=RAe%20pronombres%20personales%20atonos)

> **Colocación de los clíticos con respecto al verbo.** La colocación del pronombre átono delante o detrás del verbo no es libre, sino que está sometida a ciertas reglas, que han ido variando con el tiempo. Estas son las normas por las que se rige hoy la colocación de los clíticos en el español general culto:
>
> a) Los clíticos se anteponen, en el uso corriente, a las formas simples de indicativo: Te lo advierto: me voy. En la lengua escrita, generalmente a principio de oración o después de pausa, aparecen a veces pospuestos: «Como si adivinara mi pensamiento, díjome al punto: “La verdad es desnuda”» (RBastos Vigilia [Par. 1992]); la expresión adquiere entonces un tono arcaizante, que solo está justificado si la intención es recrear el lenguaje de épocas pasadas. El uso pospuesto es asimismo un rasgo dialectal propio de determinadas zonas del noroeste de España: Voyme enseguida; Marchose hace rato. La posposición de los clíticos es imposible cuando el verbo va en forma negativa: *No díjomelo.
>
> b) Los clíticos se anteponen también a las formas simples del subjuntivo, tanto a las independientes: Ojalá le concedan el premio; Quizá lo consiga; como a las que dependen de otro verbo (explícito o implícito): Espero que te lo pienses; Que te vaya bien.
>
> c) Los clíticos se posponen a las formas de imperativo y a las del subjuntivo exhortativo afirmativo: Hazlo; Ponételo; Dígannoslo; Hágase la luz. Es vulgar anteponer los clíticos al subjuntivo exhortativo cuando este no depende de otro verbo: «¡Se callen, carajo, no es hora de conversa!» (FnGómez Viaje [Esp. 1985]); debe decirse cállense. Sin embargo, la anteposición es obligada cuando el subjuntivo va en forma negativa o depende de otro verbo (explícito o implícito): No lo hagan; Les ordeno que se callen; Que se vayan ahora mismo.

d) e) y f) en el enlace.

Comment: Aprendi algo nuevo....A mi frases como _Nos hace sentirnos_ me sonaban bien, pero _Me hace sentirme_ me suena mal. Obviamente _Nos hace sentir_ y _Me hacen sentir_ suenan mejor.

Comment: Alex, el enlace a Google books no funciona (por violación de los términos de uso de Google).¿Lo puedes revisar?.

Comment: @DGaleano Gracias, no encuentro el libro pero se menciona en la página de fundeu.

Answer (score 4):

No estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta que han dado. No es una duplicación de pronombres, pues cada uno tiene una función diferente.

En «Te hace sentirte mal», el primer «te» corresponde al pronombre de acusativo o dativo del verbo «hacer», mientras que el segundo corresponde al pronombre reflexivo del verbo «sentirse». La prueba de que no son el mismo pronombre la tenemos en la tercera persona: «Lo/la/le hace sentirse», y no «*Se hace sentirse».

Como aclaración, digo pronombre de acusativo o dativo porque ambos son correctos, pero se prefiere el de acusativo. La explicación es esta:

Los verbos hacer y dejar, cuando tienen sentido «causativo», esto es, cuando significan, respectivamente, ‘obligar’ y ‘permitir’, siguen la misma estructura que los verbos de influencia: «verbo causativo + complemento de persona + verbo subordinado». Tanto hacer como dejar tienden a construirse con complemento directo si el verbo subordinado es intransitivo (esto es, carece de complemento directo): «Él LA hizo bajar a su estudio y le mostró el cuadro» (Aguilera Caricia [Méx. 1983]); «LO dejé hablar» (Azuela Tamaño [Méx. 1973]); y tienden a construirse con complemento indirecto cuando el segundo verbo es transitivo (es decir, lleva, a su vez, un complemento directo): «Alguien lo ayudó a incorporarse, lo estimuló y hasta LE hizo tomar café» (JmnzEmán Tramas [Ven. 1991]); «El alcaide de la cárcel LE dejaba tocar el banjo todas las mañanas» (Cela Cristo [Esp. 1988]).

Así pues, en lo que respecta a este caso concreto, vemos que tiende a construirse con el pronombre de acusativo «la», dado que «sentir», en este contexto, es intransitivo pronominal, aunque también hay ejemplos de construcción con pronombre de dativo.

Comment: Interesante. Antonio, deberías registrarte en el sitio y participar activamente. Esperamos tus aportes. A mi frases como _Nos hace sentirnos_ me sonaban bien, pero _Me hace sentirme_  me suena mal. Obviamente _Nos hace sentir_ y _Me hacen sentir_ suenan mejor.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is

> Te hace sentir.

The possessive pronoun needn't appear twice:

> Te hace sentirte.

Would be redundant (if it were grammatical in the first place).

A (roughly) analogous expression in English would be something like

> It makes you yourself feel.

The same holds for  the other examples.